# Combining nodes from separate levels into a single list in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt, grouping, xslt-2.0

What I am trying to do is take a specific node, in the example `<person>`, and combine it into a list of all the person nodes available.  Here is my sample source:

```
   <group groupName="The Little Rascals">
      <peopleInGroup>
            <people>
               <person>
                  <name value="John Doe">
                  <birthdate value="01/01/1953">
               </person>
               <person>
                  <name value="John Doe 2">
                  <birthdate value="01/01/1953">
               </person>
               <childrenInGroup>
                  <person>
                      <name value="Jane">
                      <birthdate value="01/01/1973">
                  </person>
                  <person>
                      <name value="Suzie">
                      <birthdate value="01/01/1970">
                  </person>
                </childrenInGroup>
             </people>
         </peopleInGroup>
      </group>
```

In this case what I am wanting to do is get a list of all the `<person>` elements regardless of level and loop over each one.  The list would look something like this:

```
               <person>
                  <name value="John Doe">
                  <birthdate value="01/01/1953">
               </person>
               <person>
                  <name value="John Doe 2">
                  <birthdate value="01/01/1953">
               </person>
               <person>
                   <name value="Jane">
                   <birthdate value="01/01/1973">
               </person>
               <person>
                   <name value="Suzie">
                   <birthdate value="01/01/1970">
               </person>
```

The only sorting I would want to do in this case might be by Birthday.  I was thinking that something like a Deep Copy of the `<person>` node, but I do not know what the implementation of that would look like.

Once the list is created, the idea would be to loop over the list in a for-each like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$persons">
   <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="@birthday"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the sorting you can simply use XPath with `//person` to select all `person` elements as a sequence.

If you want to sort them you can use `xsl:perform-sort`:

```
  <xsl:variable name="sorted-persons" as="element(person)*">
      <xsl:perform-sort select="descendant::person">
          <xsl:sort select="xs:date(replace(birthdate/@value, '([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})', '$3-$2-$1'))"/>
      </xsl:perform-sort>
  </xsl:variable>
```

You can then use that sorted sequence in a for-each if you want or directly output the data using `value-of`: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTyZ

Comment: I appreciate the input, but I'm really looking for an XSLT 2.0 version.  the <xsl:value-of select=$sorted-persons!()/> seems to be an XSLT 3.0 construct.  Is there a 2.0 version of this?

Comment: You asked about sorting the `person` elements and the snippet in the answer shows how to do that and is XSLT 2. The example I linked to admittedly then uses an XPath 3.1 expression to consume that sorted sequence but as the answer says, you can of course use that sequence with a `for-each` or any other construct where you can use a variable in XSLT 2.

Comment: Ok.  I agree, it does answer the initial question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="group">
        <xsl:for-each select="peopleInGroup/people/person|peopleInGroup/people/childrenInGroup/person">

                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>

        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>
```

You can use xsl:for-each and then copy person.